Reading json file from Databricks workspace
I am using second example from Databricks` official document here: Work with workspace files. But I'm getting following error:
Question: What could be a cause of the error, and how can we fix it?

Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
(named _corrupt_record by default)

Code:
%sql
SELECT * FROM json.`file:/Workspace/Users/myusername@outlook.com/myJsonFile_in_Workspace.json`;

Json file in my Databricks Workspace:
{
  "header": {
    "platform": "atm",
    "version": "2.0"
  },
  "details": [
    {
      "abc": "3",
      "def": "4"
    },
    {
      "abc": "5",
      "def": "6"
    }
  ]
}

Remarks: Minimizing JSON to single file is one possibility. The json used in my post is for explaining the question only. The actual Json that I am using is quite large and complex - and in such cases, Apache Spark's official document recommends: For a regular multi-line JSON file, set the multiline parameter to True - as shown in this example. But I'm not sure how to use this option when you're reading json from a Databrick Workspace that's what my code above is doing.

To make this code work, you must have the minified JSON on a single line.

Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for sharing your thoughts. I just added Remarks in my post above to further explain my question.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
